# Syntax Error in MYSQL clausules

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello stackoverflow's friends i need your help with this sql clausule this is the error into mysql:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE email='Tysaic0344@gmail.com'' at line 1")
```

and this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO user (token) VALUES (1) WHERE email='example@email.com'
```

Comment: are you trying to update a record or insert a new record?

Comment: @Parfait: That's not true. It also works with UPDATE and DELETE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `INSERT` with a `WHERE` clause.

If you need to `UPDATE` the record where you have the email from:

```
UPDATE user
Set token = 1
WHERE email='example@email.com'
```

Or  `INSERT` with email

```
INSERT INTO user (token, email)
 VALUES (1, 'example@email.com')
```

(or without)

```
INSERT INTO user (token)
 VALUES (1)
```

These kind of errors you MUST be able to fix by yourself, the error even tells you where it went wrong (at the end it says "near 'WHERE...").

Check the docs that dns_nx included (**especially** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html ) for the correct syntax to do an update.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot insert values into an existing row. You can either update or delete the existing records. In your case, I think you want to update the existing row. You can use **UPDATE**.

```
UPDATE user SET token = 1 WHERE email = 'example@email.com';
```

If you want to add records to the table use **INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO user VALUES (1, 'example@email.com');
```

Here is the link for your reference

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243852(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `INSERT` a value into an existing row. The `WHERE` clause is invalid with `INSERT`. If you want to update an existing row, then you have to `UPDATE` the field like this:

```
UPDATE 
  user
SET
  token = 1 
WHERE 
  email='example@email.com'
```

Please review the docs about `INSERT` and `UPDATE`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

[`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) inserts new rows into a table. The `WHERE` clause is used to filter existing rows from a table. It doesn't make sense in a `INSERT` query; that's why the [`INSERT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) does not contain a `WHERE` clause.

The `WHERE` clause is used to filter the rows to fetch from the table (the [`SELECT` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)), the rows to modify (the [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)) or to remove from the table (the [`DELETE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)).

Your query looks like you want to modify the data already existing in the table. The [`UPDATE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) you need looks like this:

```
UPDATE user SET token = 1 WHERE email = 'example@email.com'
```